# Always consume from queue, while grouping similar items

Tags: python, logic, global-variables

#### Note: This is a minimum reproducible example of a real life situation

#### Flow of steps:

**1. I add tasks to a message queue.**
tasks e.g.

("analysis_id": 10, "cell":"A")

("analysis_id": 10, "cell":"B")

("analysis_id": 10, "cell":"C")

("analysis_id": 11, "cell":"A")

("analysis_id": 11, "cell":"B")

*As you can see, each analysis_id can multiple cells.*

**2. I have a consumer that consumes 'each' task and processes it**

e.g. `python3.7 run_my_tasks.py -analysis_id <analysis_id> -cell <cell>`

**3.  My consumer needs to be always be alive**

That means, the consumer callback needs to always be waiting for new messages.

**4. I need to be able to group the similar analysis_id cells into one list, and process them together**

So what I'm looking to achieve is:

list_to_send = [A, B, C]

list_to_send = [A, B]

**5. By doing this, if I'm appending to the old list, I can append. And if I need to create a new list, I can send the old list, `list_to_send = []`, and then start appending once again**

Here is what I've come up with, but I'm not entirely sure that I can get this to work. I have commented within the code to show my logic.

```py
from time import sleep

"""
Initially analysis_id and list_to_send are both empty. 
In the actual code, my consumer will get the json from the message queue, and the json contains both analysis_id and cell.

In pseudo code:

If it's a new analysis_id (not same as the previous)
    Send the previous list for processing
    Create new_list
    Append to new_list
If it's the same as previous analysis_id
    append to list
And so on...
"""


analysis_id = "TGSA"
list_to_send = []

# This is my message queue. Think of TGSA as analysis_id: 10, and TGSB as analysis_id: 11, and TGSC as analysis_id: 12
rab_q = ["TGSA", "TGSA", "TGSA", "TGSA", "TGSB",
         "TGSB", "TGSC", "TGSC", "TGSC", "TGSC", "TGSD", "TGSD", "TGSD", "TGSD", "TGSD", "TGSD"]


def my_func(_id):
    # Use the gloabl variables
    global analysis_id
    global list_to_send

    # if list_to_send is empty (which initially it should be)
    if not list_to_send:
        # append the analysis_id "TGS*" to my list to send
        if _id == analysis_id:
            # First is equal, so append to list.
            list_to_send.append(_id)
        elif _id != analysis_id:
            # If the list is empty, and the analysis_id are different
            # change analysis_id and append to list
            analysis_id = _id
            list_to_send.append(analysis_id)
    # if list_to_send is NOT empty
    else:
        # If the analysis_id is equal, append
        if _id == analysis_id:
            list_to_send.append(_id)
        # If analysis_id is not equal, and list is NOT empty, that means this is a new run
        elif _id != analysis_id:
            # print(list_to_send) is basically where I will send_tasks(list_to_send)
            print(list_to_send)
            # list_to_send has been sent for processing, reinstantiate an empty list
            list_to_send = []
            # and append the current analysis_id to the new list
            analysis_id = _id
            list_to_send.append(analysis_id)


# Add each message to my `callback` or `consumer`
for i in rab_q:
    my_func(i)
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is never exit out of the consumer/callback and yet, group similar analysis_id's together, send the list of analysis_id's for processing, and then empty list again to be ready for the next level of analysis_ids.

I've got it to work, BUT, it skips the latest analysis_id. Run the code to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has this unique use case in the future, here's how I managed to solve it.

If anyone has a more efficient way of solving this, i'm quite eager to see your solution.

```py
from time import sleep

analysis_id = "TGSA"
list_to_send = []
last_message = False
rab_q = ["TGSA", "TGSA", "TGSA", "TGSA", "TGSB",
         "TGSB", "TGSC", "TGSC", "TGSC", "TGSC",
         "TGSD", "TGSD", "TGSD", "TGSD", "TGSD", "TGSD"]


def my_func(_id):

    global analysis_id
    global list_to_send
    global last_message
    global count

    if not list_to_send:

        if _id == analysis_id:

            list_to_send.append(_id)
        elif _id != analysis_id:

            analysis_id = _id
            list_to_send.append(analysis_id)

    else:

        if _id == analysis_id and not last_message:
            list_to_send.append(_id)

        elif _id != analysis_id:
            print(f'send this for processong: {list_to_send}')
            list_to_send = []
            analysis_id = _id
            list_to_send.append(analysis_id)
        elif _id == analysis_id and last_message:
            print(f'send this for processong: {list_to_send}')
            list_to_send = []
            analysis_id = ""
            count = 0
            last_message = False


# Add each message to my `callback` or `consumer`
total_cur_jobs = len(rab_q)
count = 0

for i in rab_q:
    count += 1
    if count == total_cur_jobs:
        last_message = True
    my_func(i)

print(
    f"now that all the processing has ended lets see what we have \n analysis_id: {analysis_id}, list_to_send: {list_to_send}, last_message: {last_message} and finally, count: {count}")
```